# Spring MVC internationalization, Locale country attribute is empty

Tags: spring, internationalization

I have a problem with i18n in Spring MVC. When I call this method to get the current locale:

```
public static final Locale DEFAULT_LOCALE = new Locale("en", "GB");

public Locale getLocale() {
    if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null) {
        final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        final LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils
                .getLocaleResolver(request);
        if (localeResolver != null) {
            Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);
            if (locale != null) {
                return locale;
            }
        }
    }
    return DEFAULT_LOCALE;
}
```

it returns the correct locale but without the country attribute set.

```
public String getCurrency() {
    Locale locale = getLocale();
    System.err.println("Locale: " + getLocale());
    String country = locale.getCountry();
    System.err.println("Country: " + country);
    String displayCountry = locale.getDisplayCountry();
    System.err.println("displayCountry: " + displayCountry);
    String displayName = locale.getDisplayName();
    System.err.println("displayName: " + displayName);
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    System.err.println("Currency.getSymbol() = " + currency.getSymbol());
    return currency.getSymbol();
}
```

This method prints:

```
Locale: ro
Country: 
displayCountry: 
displayName: Romanian
```

I actually need to get the locale currency but this call Currency.getInstance(locale); throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException because of the country attribute is empty.

This is the configuration file I use for internationalization:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
   <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I think the problem is that when I select a new country it changes only the language.

Here is where I change the language:

```
<a class="country_flag" href="?lang=uk">United Kingdom</a>
<a class="country_flag" href="?lang=ro">Romania</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use SessionLocaleResolver and it does work for me:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="ru_RU" />
</bean>
```

Pay an attention - value should be xx_XX, despite of lang=xx in the jsp:

```
    <li><a href="?lang=en"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/languages/en.png"/>" border="0"/></li>
    <li><a href="?lang=ru"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/languages/ru.png"/>" border="0"/></li>
```